# DomPDF not showing images when center-aligned

Tags: dompdf

I have multiple forms with tinyMCE textareas that saves content to the database in order to generate a PDF with the content from the database. The user can input text or images to the textarea.

Whenever the user center-align the image with TinyMCE, it doesn't show in the PDF. It doesn't give me any errors, it simply doesn't show. If I go back to the form and right-align the image, it shows again, but the users of the system required full control of the interface.

does anyone knows what could be causing this?

Notes:

- I'm aware of [this bug](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/issues/98) however none of the suggestions I found there fixes my issue.
- I'm using [Laravel-dompdf](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf)

This is a sample of the view that is being used by DOMPDF, the image is contained within product description.

```
 <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <title>{{Lang::choice('page_elements/general.proposal', 2)}}</title>
    <style type="text/css">
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="product_section">
       <div class="text-block">{{($proposalProduct->description)}}</div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is a sample of what the product description (formatted by TinyMCE) is returning.

```
<p>This is a sample product, using images and tinyMCE.</p>
<p><img style="-webkit-user-select: none; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;"   src="http://mywebsite.com/products/images/product1.png" alt="" /></p>
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Discussion also happening here: https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/issues/861